# select showing undefined but console log shows value angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My select is the following

```
                <div class="inputCol">
                    <label>{{'FrequentBeneficiary'  | translate}}</label>
                    <select ng-model="params.beneficiary" ng-options="option.Name as option.Name for option in beneficiaryData"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my service call code:

```
  bcsSQLiteStorage.getDataDB(BeneficiariesKey).then(function (data) {
                if (data.rows.length > 0) {

                    console.log("entrou no data.rows.length");
                    $scope.beneficiariesData = angular.fromJson(data.rows.item(0).value);
                    $scope.AccountLoaded = true;
                    MobileLoading.Ionic.hide();
                    console.log("Beneficiaries Data " + JSON.stringify($scope.beneficiariesData));
                    $scope.params.beneficiary = $scope.beneficiariesData[0].Name;
                    console.log($scope.params.beneficiary);
                }
```

and my console.log prints the name just fine

```
 console.log($scope.params.beneficiary);

prints the name correctly, does not print undefined
```

but my select shows undefined when I am testing it 
why? something wrong with my select?

Comment: I hope your options contains the beneficiary value which you are setting up as model.

Comment: Diljohn5741 I am giving the value with  $scope.params.beneficiary = $scope.beneficiariesData[0].Name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $scope.params.beneficiary=null before calling service means outside of service function block then test once again